# Какие отношения типов использовать в SFINAE для конструктора с perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

Несколько запутался с проверкой типов в SFINAE. Допустим, есть:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::string member;
    std::string member2;

    template <
        typename T, // Parameter 1.
        typename U, // Parameter 2.
        typename Enable = typename std::enable_if <
        std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value &&
        std::is_constructible<std::string, U>::value>::type>
    Foo(T&& member, U&& member2) :
        member{std::forward<T>(member)},
        member2{std::forward<U>(member2)}
    {}
};
```

Не пойму, что нужно использовать, `std::is_constructible` или же `std::is_convertible` или `std::is_same`? Про последний, так понимаю жесткое совпадение нам обеспечено, можно еще `std::decay` только добавить. Однако хотелось бы строку инициализировать С-массивом или, например, вектор через `std::initializer_list`. Про `std::is_convertible` знаю, что пропустит, например, преобразование `float` в `int`, однако в таком коде:

```
template<class D>
    impl_ptr(pointer p, D&& d,
             typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_convertible<D, deleter_type>::value,
                dummy_t_
             >::type = dummy_t_()) noexcept
    : ptr_(std::move(p), std::forward<D>(d)) {}
```

используется (этот пример - конструктор smart-указателя для реализации pimpl, `D` и `deleter_type` - это удалители, `ptr_` имеет тип `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: Никакое, `std::enable_if` тут вообще ни к чему.

Comment: @VTT к тому, что у нас универсальные ссылки и шаблон, проверка типов нужна для таких конструкторов. Первый пример - может и нет, соглашусь, надуманно, но в общем случае - нужно. Не понимаю, достаточно ли указывать `is_convertible`? Где можно посмотреть проектирование таких проверок типов?

Comment: Они нужны когда у вас *несколько* перегруженных вариантов шаблонной функции с разной логикой. Тогда вопрос "что выбрать" стоять не будет, так как каждый вариант будет иметь ясные задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::is_convertible` подразумевает именно и только *неявные* преобразования, со всеми сопутствующими ограничениями, налагаемыми на неявные преобразования. Он не будет принимать во внимание конвертирующие конструкторы и операторы приведения типа, помеченные как `explicit`. Он не будет выполнять более одного пользовательского преобразования в последовательности преобразований.

`std::is_constructible` напрямую рассматривает именно конструкторы, причем независимо то того, помечены ли они как `explicit`.

То есть разделение тут совершено четкое и [примерно] соответствует разнице между прямой инициализацией `T a(b)` и инициализацией копированием `T a = b`. Даже в С++17 различия между этими формами инициализации не сводятся только к `explicit`.

Выбирайте, что именно вам нужно в вашем случае.

У вас сейчас `is_constructible`, что фактически вытаскивает наружу все конструкторы `std::string`, включая конструкцию из аллокатора. Вам нужна такая возможность? Подозреваю, что исходный замысел был в том, чтобы разрешить только конструкцию из разнообразных видов строк. А тогда уместнее именно `is_convertible`.

Comment: Пожалуй, я согласен с Вашим последним абзацем. Рассмотрел пример с конструкцией вектора (а не строки) из числа, т.е. создание N элементов в векторе. constructible дает такую возможность, но только добавляет путаницы в пользовательском коде. convertible действительно уместнее, т.о. требуется явно собрать lvalue или rvalue вектор или еще что-то в него преобразуемое и передать. Вопрос дополнительный - а где же реально применим constructible?

Answer (score 1):

В подобных случаях лучше использовать `std::is_constructible`, потому что вы передаёте аргумент в конструктор, а значит и проверять вам нужно существование конструктора для данных аргументов.

Но для конкретно приведённого примера лучше использовать string_view (если доступен), или принимать стоки по значению и передавать через `std::move`. Вариант с шаблонной реализацией создаёт больше проблем, чем пользы.

А `std::is_convertible` для удалителей в умных указателях используется из-за того, что удалителем может быть лямбда, которая неявно преобразуется в указатель на функцию, но указатель на функцию не конструируется напрямую из лямбды.

Comment: "... но указатель на функцию не конструируется напрямую из лямбды."? О чем это? Указатель на функцию прекрасно "конструируется" из "captureless" лямбды. Никакой разницы с преобразованием тут нет.